# PDF995 set Product code to create 2 documents

Tags: c#, dialog, registry

I have a c# method that needs to create two documents separately using PDF995. The simplified version:

```
public void PrintDocuments(PrintDocument report1, PrintDocument report2) {

    PrintUtility.SetPDF995Key();  // Method to set the product code in the registry.
    report1.Print();      // PDF995 "Save as" dialog box appears here.

    PrintUtility.SetPDF995Key();
    report2.Print();

}
```

In order to create a document and avoid having all the PDF995 advertising banners appear, I first have to set the Product Code as a Registry item. However as soon as you click on `Save` in the PDF995 Save File Dialog, the product key is blanked out, which means I would have to set the Product Code again to create the second document.

The problem is, the Save File dialog box is displayed as an asynchronous / modeless dialog box, which means that the code which creates the second document is reached before the user has had a chance to click on `Save` for the first one.

So now, even though the Product Code is set a second time, clicking on `Save` for the first document will blank it out, and because the program has already passed the call to the `PrintUtility.SetPDF995Key()` method before printing the second one, it will still be blank when the second Save File Dialog appears and so I get the annoying "Trial version" banners.

So is there any way around this? e.g. is there a way to make the Save As dialog Modal, or an event when "Save" is clicked that can be fired so I can call `PrintUtility.SetPDF995Key()` immediately, or some way of permanently setting the Product Code or something else?

Comment: Is the use of Pdf995 mandatory or may you consider to use another free pdf printer allowing to eliminate the SaveDialog ?

Comment: @Graffito unfortunately yes...

Comment: **If** the registry key is cleared after the save file dialog, you may "wait" for a blank registry key before calling report 2.Print.

Comment: @Graffito Thanks I ended up doing this - didn't really want to at first as I was worried that instability could cause the key to be incorrectly set and the application to be held up forever, but I put the printing routine in a thread on its own and clear the Product Code deliberately before entering it and it seems to be doing the job.